# Series bounded by uniform convergent series is uniform convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, power-series, uniform-convergence

I was reading about the Weierstrass $M$-test, and I was wondering about the following:

> Suppose that $(f_{n})$ is a sequence of real-valued functions defined on a set $A$, and there exists $(g_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \geq 0$ defined on $A$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}g_{i}$ is uniformly convergent on $A$, and for all $n\in \mathbb{N}, x \in A$, $|f_{n}(x)|\leq g_{n}(x)$. Then does $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}f_i$ converge absolutely and uniformly on $A$?

I think this is true by a slight modification of the original proof. However, I cannot find anything online relating to this. So is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true by checking the Cauchy criterion for the partial sums of the series $\sum f_n(x)$, the same way as is done for the $M$-test. Since $\sum g_n(x)$ converges uniformly for $x\in A$, for each $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N(\epsilon)$ such that if $p,q\ge N$, for all $x\in A$,
$$
|\sum_{n=p}^qf_n(x)| \le\sum_{n=p}^q|f_n(x)|\le \sum_{n=p}^q g_n(x) < \epsilon.
$$
This implies that the partial sums of the series $\sum |f_n(x)|$ are uniformly Cauchy, so $\sum f_n(x)$ is uniformly and absolutely convergent in $x\in A$.

Comment: Thank you. This is basically what I have done. It seems to be quite useful immediate corollary. I don't know why I cannot find it online.

Comment: @wsz_fantasy: It probably has some applications in the theory of Riemann integration when it comes to integrating a series term by term. My guess to why it's not highlighted is that quickly after learning real analysis and then the Lebesgue integral, we dispense with a lot of the particulars of series, since the theory of Lebesgue integration has a few neat theorems regarding swapping integrals and limits that are more flexible and general than those concerning the Riemann integral.